# How to hide the segments button and display other segments button

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am having a problem in displaying the segment button on the navigation bar. My program flow is like this: Login page > details page > map page.
I also want to display the 2 segments button on the details page And when goto the Map page then user sees 3 segments button. How is this possible?

More information about my  project: in this app i have the tabbar also for that i create the other class it's name is tabbar class. And i am calling all page.

```
TTabBar *tabbar=[[TTabBar alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabbar animated:YES];
tabbar.selectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: you need to have 2 segments and then add other segment in map page

Comment: *details page* & *map page* aren't two different pages/view controllers? Adding a segment controller in each page won't bother one another, right?

Comment: @jignesh how can add the segment in map page .Because I already make code for  segment button in the tabbar class

Comment: @Shima, Check my answer, you can insert segments thorugh code for map page and details page

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding segments from code using following

```
    segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(115, 210, 190, 30)];
    segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    [segmentedControl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bus.png"] atIndex:0 animated:YES];
    [segmentedControl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"car.png"] atIndex:1 animated:YES];
    [segmentedControl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"walking.png"] atIndex:2 animated:YES];
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex =0;
    segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor greyColor];
    [mainView addSubview:segmentedControl];
```

Comment: are know about how can make the analog clock

Comment: sorry, Did not get you? Can you elaborate your comment?

Comment: Actually I also want know how can create the Analog Clock.I want know how can i move image like the clock

Comment: there is one trick, you can take image of let say 240 height, and have hour,minute and second images starts from 0 - 120, and rest part 120-240 will be transparent, and move it from center

Comment: @Shima: Code
//rotation
CABasicAnimation *fullRotation;
fullRotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
fullRotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
fullRotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];
fullRotation.duration = 6;
fullRotation.repeatCount = 1e100f;

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are adding segment control as leftBarButtonItem or rightBarButtonItem. How about setting barButtonItem to nil and add the new one?

Comment: UIBarButtonItem is different than UISegmentedControl

Comment: you are saying to add entire UISegmentedControl to leftBarButtonItem?

Comment: UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Activitieslist.png"],nil]];UIBarButtonItem *segmentBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];[segmentedControl release];self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = segmentBarItem;
[segmentBarItem release];

Comment: But when i add the one more segment it will show me on 1st page but not on the map page which is my 2nd page it only show me the two segment only on map page

Comment: how you are displaying map page by pushing it on navigation stack or somehow different way?

Comment: @Jignesh Brahmkhatri yes my dear friend.